# Symfony 6 Custom Authenticator ignored

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, symfony6

I need to configure a custom authenticator in Symfony 6 but it is being ignored. My api/login route will use my controller but it will never go through my custom authenticator. If I print out with "php bin/console config:dump-reference security" what my application see's, my custom Authenticator is not present.

Here is my service.yaml

```yaml
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: Username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\ApiAuthenticator
            lazy: true
            json_login:
                check_path: api_login
                username_path: security.credentials.username
                password_path: security.credentials.password
            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true
    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: '^/api/login', role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

I expect my application to use my /api/login route and authenticate the user using my custom authenticator.

Comment: Please Show your Authenticator. Especially the supports() method.

Answer (score 0):

well I dont know for sure but it seems like json_login is rewriting your custom_authenticators

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems"? Can you share how you've detected this, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining multiple authenticator in one firewall. So you have to tell symfony which one it should check first by defining entry_point.

```
firewalls:
    main:
        # allow authentication using a form or a custom authenticator
        form_login: ~
        custom_authenticators:
            - App\Security\SocialConnectAuthenticator

        # configure the form authentication as the entry point for unauthenticated users
        entry_point: form_login
```

[See documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entry_point.html)